# What is a good browser for a publicly accessible computer?

Tags: web-browser

Im setting up a computer in a hotel lobby and it needs to not have any history or remembered information between browsing sessions. Chrome is the most compatible browser but it seems difficult (if even possible) to completely disable history. Firefox is ok but i really don't care for the newest version of it. Edit: I also need to be able to prevent users from creating bookmarks and installing addons. Is there a way to force Chrome and/or Firefox to always use Private Browsing? Is there another browser out there built specifically for this purpose?

Comment: On Linux firefox has a system-wide /etc/firefox wtih a profile that can force settings onto a user's profile and cannot be overriden.

Comment: Caution:  If the computer is physically accessible, it is hard to secure.  If hacked it could be set to appear to reboot, or even reboot, but not before sending details of the session somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best option would be to run a cut down Linux installation with Chrome/Chromium or Firefox that runs in RAM only, starts straight into the browser  and then reboots on exit.

It will be fast to operate and allow no changes to the settings, bookmarks, history, cookies, etc. to be preserved between sessions - you could even run it from a USB that has a physical switch for read-only mode to further ensure that nobody can make changes with any lasting impact.

An example of setting this sort of thing up can be found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/).

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea a lot....I almost wonder if Chrome OS would be a good choice....I hate Chrome OS personally, but it could be ideal for a public terminal...depending on how annoying it is to use lol

Comment: @Braden'sPC's: Personally I would be tempted to use a RaspberryPy 3 with the same sort of OS changes.